# How to sanitize Rails API params

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api-design

I'm making my own API and I was wondering: How to secure the received params?

Example:

- I have a Car model with `brand` and `color` attributes.

My endpoint receives those params in the payload. With this received payload I search in my db:

```rb
car = Car.where(color: params[:color])
# or
car = Car.find_by(brand: params[:brand])
# or writing
Car.first.update!(brand: params[:brand])
```

But I'm so worried about what if someone tries to exploit with SQL or XSS?
How do you work with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The examples from your question are all protected against SQL injection automatically.

Relevant quotes from the official [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-introduction):

> **7.2.1 Introduction**
>
> SQL injection attacks aim at influencing database queries by manipulating web application parameters. A popular goal of SQL injection attacks is to bypass authorization. Another goal is to carry out data manipulation or reading arbitrary data. Here is an example of how **not to use user** input data in a query:
>
> ```
> Project.where("name = '#{params[:name]}'")
> ```

Then later in the [same document](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-countermeasures):

> **7.2.4 Countermeasures**
>
> Ruby on Rails has a built-in filter for special SQL characters, which will escape `'` , `"` , NULL character, and line breaks. Using `Model.find(id)` or `Model.find_by_some thing(something)` automatically applies this countermeasure. But in SQL fragments, especially in conditions fragments (`where("...")`), the `connection.execute()` or `Model.find_by_sql()` methods, it has to be applied manually.
>
> Instead of passing a string, you can use positional handlers to sanitize tainted strings like this:
>
> ```
> Model.where("zip_code = ? AND quantity >= ?", entered_zip_code, entered_quantity).first
> ```
>
> The first parameter is a SQL fragment with question marks. The second and third parameter will replace the question marks with the value of the variables.
>
> You can also use named handlers, the values will be taken from the hash used:
>
> ```
> values = { zip: entered_zip_code, qty: entered_quantity }
> Model.where("zip_code = :zip AND quantity >= :qty", values).first
> ```
>
> Additionally, you can split and chain conditionals valid for your use case:
>
> ```
> Model.where(zip_code: entered_zip_code).where("quantity >= ?", entered_quantity).first
> ```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for all !
I'm very happy. I didn't find this guide when i searched on Google.

Thanks again for your message ! :)

Comment: The [Rails Guides] are part of the official documentation of Ruby on Rails. I highly recommend reading it.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, Rails takes care of SQL injection.
So, you should avoid passing strings as parameters to Active Records methods. Avoid this:

`Car.where("color = '#{params[:color]'")`

Instead, use arrays or hashes:

`car = Car.where(color: params[:color])`

`car = Car.where(["color = ?", params[:color])`

By doing so, Active Records will automatically escape unwanted characters, protecting against SQL injection.

---

For more, see Rails doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-countermeasures

---

I updated this response after @spickermann reported a significant mistake.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer ! :)

I took time to read your answer and links. Thanks !
I understood what to do to avoid most of SQL injections.

But i don't understand technically how "putting it an array" avoid the SQL injection hmm..

Comment: `car = Car.where(color: params[:color])` is actually more idiomatic in Rails and would prevent SQL injection. And please be aware that `where` and `find_by` are very different methods, `where` returns a chainable relation whereas `find_by` returns a single record.

Comment: Oh so you don't agree with Alessandro? (sorry i don't speak english very well ahah). Aaah, I'm undecided now.

EDIT: Yes, i'm okay with differences between `find` and `where`, thank you !! :)

Comment: Yes, I disagree. See the third example of how to prevent SQL injection in the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-countermeasures). That is exactly how you do it in your question. This is the preferred way to secure your app. There is nothing wrong with using the Hash syntax.

Comment: Yes @spickermann, I agree with you. I've updated the response.  Thanks!